# Class change span on hover parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m looking for simple solution of this:
I need change class of span, when i hover parent element (button):

my HTML:

```
<button id="show_container_2">
   <span id="show_container_2_span" class="cl">TEXT</span>
</button>
```

and JS (using Jquery):

```
$("#show_container_2").hover(
    function(){
        $("#show_container_2_span").removeClass("cl");
        $("#show_container_2_span").addClass("cl_hover");
    },
    function(){
        $("#show_container_2_span").removeClass("cl_hover");
        $("#show_container_2_span").addClass("cl");
    }
);
```

But this is not working. Any ideas or simplier solutions? Thanks!

Comment: nothing looks wrong in your code, can you reproduce the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: Did you put your jQuery code within $(document).ready()?

Comment: It works like a charm - http://jsfiddle.net/LcSalazar/0h1paozz/

Comment: As per your code, it's fit and fine, i know it basics, but still have you included your JQuery Library. Works here - http://jsfiddle.net/qq3g5j3n/

Comment: Hope he had forgot to include the Jquery library!! The code is perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do this action on doc ready or other similar events

```
  $(function() {

    $("#show_container_2").hover(
      function () {
        $("#show_container_2_span").removeClass("cl");
        $("#show_container_2_span").addClass("cl_hover");
      },
      function () {
        $("#show_container_2_span").removeClass("cl_hover");
          $("#show_container_2_span").addClass("cl");
      }
    );

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but since you asked for

> simplier solutions

I would suggest using

> .toggleClass()

```
$("#show_container_2").hover(function () {
    $("#show_container_2_span").toggleClass("cl_hover");
  }
);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codotronix/0h1paozz/5/) for the same